# Iterating through values of a paired RDD (Pyspark) and replacing null values

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, group-by, rdd

I am collecting data using the Spark RDD API and have created a paired RDD, as shown below:

```
spark = SparkSession.builder.master('local').appName('app').getOrCreate()
sc = spark.sparkContext
raw_rdd = sc.textFile("data.csv")

paired_rdd = raw_rdd\
    .map(lambda x: x.split(","))\
    .map(lambda x: (x[2], [x[1], x[3],x[5]]))
```

Here is a sample excerpt of the paired RDD:

```
[('VXIO456XLBB630221', ['I', 'Nissan', '2003']),
 ('VXIO456XLBB630221', ['A', '', '']),
 ('VXIO456XLBB630221', ['R', '', '']),
 ('VXIO456XLBB630221', ['R', '', ''])]
```

As you notice, the keys in this paired RDD are the same for all elements, but only one element has all the fields completed.

What do we want to accomplish? We want to replace the empty fields with the values of the element with complete fields. So we would have an expected output like this:

```
[('VXIO456XLBB630221', ['I', 'Nissan', '2003']),
 ('VXIO456XLBB630221', ['A', 'Nissan', '2003']), 
 ('VXIO456XLBB630221', ['R', 'Nissan', '2003']), 
 ('VXIO456XLBB630221', ['R', 'Nissan', '2003'])]
```

I know the first step would be to do a `groupByKey`, i.e.,

```
paired_rdd.groupByKey().map(lambda kv: ____)
```

I am just not sure how to iterate through the values and how this would fit into one lambda function.

Comment: Could there be akey change?

Comment: Hello! For the sake of brevity, the excerpt had only one id. However, the whole RDD has different id's. From the other fields available, this would be the only appropriate key, since it is a car's unique identifier. I was thinking earlier about making a function that can iterate through the array of values and pick out the values that are non-empty.  I just don't really know how to connect that back with the mapping function, since that one goes row by row. Sorry if I am being too abstract. Thank you!

Comment: Well i have a few clues, but for the sake of brevity just replace null values for given key.

Comment: Does the 1st record always have values?

Comment: That's a good point. For this specific dataset, yes. The records are mixed but every time a new identifier is introduced, all of the values are present.

Comment: can it be dataframe not RDD?

Comment: This is one specific section of the code. The later parts would involve a reduction step, which I believe is greater facilitated through RDD. But, I guess we could convert to dataframe and then re-convert back to RDD.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way would probably to go with dataframes and window functions. With RDDs, you could work something out as well with an aggregation (`reduceByKey`) that would fill in the blanks and keep in memory the list of first elements of the list. Then we could re flatten based on that memory to create the same number of rows as before but with the values filled in.

```py
# let's define a function that selects the none empty values between two strings
def select_value(a, b):
    if a is None or len(a) == 0:
         return b
    else:
         return a

# let's use mapValues to separate the first element of the list and the rest
# Then we use reduceByKey to aggregate the list of all first elements (first
# element of the tuple). For the other elements, we only keep non empty values
# (second element of the tuple).
# Finally, we use flatMapValues to recreate the rows based on the memorized
# first elements of the lists.
paired_rdd\
    .mapValues(lambda x: ([x[0]], x[1:]))\
    .reduceByKey(lambda a, b: (
            a[0] + b[0],
            [select_value(a[1][i], b[1][i]) for i in range(len(a[1])) ] 
     ) )\
    .flatMapValues(lambda x: [[k] + x[1]  for k in x[0]])\
    .collect()
```

Which yields:

```
[('VXIO456XLBB630221', ['I', 'Nissan', '2003']),
 ('VXIO456XLBB630221', ['A', 'Nissan', '2003']),
 ('VXIO456XLBB630221', ['R', 'Nissan', '2003']),
 ('VXIO456XLBB630221', ['R', 'Nissan', '2003'])
]
```

Comment: This is an awesome set of logic. I recently started learning Spark, and while I can understand the reason for its lazy logic evaluation, I really wish there was a better way to "preview" the intermediate steps of the programming logic. Thank you, once again for your input, and that really superb lambda function!